# res.status is not a function Next.js 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new to Next js and I am facing a problem whole day

This is my api for checking in mongoDB if user exists

```
import {connect} from '../../../../lib/mongodb';
import User from '../../../models/userModel';

export async function POST(req, res) {
    try {
        // Get email from request body
        const {email} = await req.json();

        // Connect to database
        await connect();

        // Find user by email
        const user = await User.findOne({email});

        // If user exists, return error
        if (user) {
            return res.status(400).json({message: "User already exists"});
        } else {
            // Return response
            return res.status(201).json({message: "Email is non registered."});
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).json({message: "Something went wrong while register"});
    }
}
```

`TypeError: res.status is not a function`

I tried to switch req with res, I tried to use NextResponse and NextRequest but I read that they are used only in middleware

Answer (score 0):

You can write this:

```
const response = {
  success: 'Logged in successfully'
};
return new Response(JSON.stringify(response), {
  status: 200,
  headers: {
    "message": "Blurblur~"
  },
});
}

else 
  
return NextResponse.status(200).json({
  error: 'Authentication failed'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `Response` object

```js
if (user) {
   return new Response.json({ message: "User already exists" },
       {
           status: 200,
           headers: {
               "content-type": "application/json"
           }
       })
}
else {
   return new Response.json({ message: "Email is non registered" },
       {
           status: 404,
           headers: { "content-type": "application/json" }
       })
}
```

> TypeScript Warning: Response.json() is only valid from TypeScript 5.2. If you use a lower TypeScript version, you can use NextResponse.json() for typed responses instead.